# Dexterity content type Hiding setting tab

Tags: plone, dexterity

On my Dexterity content type I have a default tab where all my defined fields are loaded and settings tab where the `ExcludeFromNav` checkbox is, which I defaulted to checked when a new object is created.

I would like to hide this setting tab as user don't need to see it. I presume that it will be different from just hiding a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabs are automatically shown if there are fields visible in it.

The easiest way to not show a tab then, is to hide all fields that are part of it. Hide the `ExcludeFromNav` field or move it to a different tab, and the *Settings* tab will not be shown.